# Add another project jar as a resource

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java multi-project in gradle, its structure is like that:

```
root
+ Project A
+ Project B
\ Project C
```

and there dependency:

```
Project A
\ Other stuff (normal 'api' dependency)

Project B
+ Project A (normal 'api' dependency)
\ Other stuff (normal 'api' dependency)

Project C
+ Project A (normal 'api' dependency)
+ Project B (need jar)
\ Other stuff (normal 'api' dependency)
```

Project C need to be able to run the assembled version of project B in a separate JVM. Later the goal is to have project B and C to run on different machine, where project C will act as the controller that will deploy project B with args on something like AWS. But for now, i need to be able to test it locally.

Edit:
I have this code in root project to go fetch all subproject's distribution zip.

```
subprojects.each { subproject ->
  evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path)
}
task multiprojectJar(type: Copy,dependsOn: subprojects.assemble) {
  into 'localDeploy'
  subprojects.each { subproject ->
    into(""){
      from subproject.configurations.archives.artifacts.files.findAll{ file ->
        file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.')+1) == 'zip'
      }.collect { file ->
        zipTree(file)// if folder in zip needed
        //file //if zip needed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to include only the zip of project B in a resource folder of project C

Edit 2:
I am now able to get the distribution zip from project B, but just by putting it on the classpath of project C.

Project B build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    assembledZip{
        canBeConsumed = true
        canBeResolved = false
    }
}
dependencies {
    api project(':projectA')
}
artifacts {
    assembledZip(
        configurations.archives.artifacts.files.findAll{ file ->
            file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.')+1) == 'zip'
        }.collect { file ->
            file
        }
    )
}
```

Project C build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    api project(':projectA')
    runtimeOnly project(path: ':projectB', configuration: 'assembledZip')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependency in your compile function as given below.

```
task compilecom_ofss_ob_infra(type: JavaCompile) {
        mustRunAfter ':compileproject_A:jarPojectA'
        source = fileTree(dir: '/path/to/src', include: '**/*.java')
        destinationDir = file('/path/to/buildspace')
        options.fork = 'true'
        options.forkOptions.with {
            memoryMaximumSize = '2048m'
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath = fileTree(include: ['**/*.jar'], dir: '/path/to/projectA.jar')

        }   
    }
```

To handle the execution order you can use `must run after` and `should run after` 
When you use the “must run after” ordering rule you specify that taskB must always run after taskA, whenever both taskA and taskB will be run. This is expressed as taskB.mustRunAfter(taskA).

For more info follow the official [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) it is well explained and simple to use

Comment: Project A in my example is imported as a simple library like : dependencies { api project(':ProjectA') }

and if i tried your example with project B and C, B become part of C's classpath. But B is not a library but an application.

Comment: Before i do, just to be sure. Why you go get your src directly rather than using the java plugin with sourceSet? Why do you specify the build destination that way, that will break everything else that need the output, shouldn't you have used a configurations for that? Why do I need another daemon process(options.fork)? And the question is for Project B and C, not project A. How does your example work with project B and C?

Comment: I tried different variations of your example, but it is not doing what I need